# Insert a linebreak only if there was none before

Tags: line-breaking

I am looking for a way to tell TeX:

Please break that line if and only if you are not on new line already.

I need this for a new environment which should always start in a new line. But I don't (how could I?) know, whether the author has typed a linebreak in front of that manually. I tried `\linebreak`, `\\`, and `\newline`, all of them caused the

> LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

error, which I expected to show up, when trying

```
\newenvironment{mynewenvironment}{\\ \emph{Header:} }{}
[...]
random text \\
\begin{mynewenvironment}
text again
\end{mynewenvironment}
```

One can observe the same behavior with predefined environments, for instance

```
random text 
\begin{itemize}
\\ \item text
\end{itemize}
```

is causing the error but not

```
random text

\begin{itemize}
\item text
\end{itemize}

random text\begin{itemize}
\item text
\end{itemize}
```

Both are doing exactly how I want my environment to react, therefore I expect my problem to be solvable fairly easy, but I don't know how.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! There should be no reason to _use a manual line break_ at all. Maybe if you put `\par` or an empty line there?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should almost never use `\\` in a document other than ending tabular rows. Just use `\par` with an appropriate setting of `\parskip` and `\parindent`. Or for more general display environments copy the definition of the latex environments such as `center` or `quote` which are all defined in terms of `list` or `trivlist` which enables them to detect whether the following text needs to start a new paragraph or not. `quote` for example is simply defined as:

```
\newenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! `\par` does the trick I was looking for, and with the hints from the quote environment I am very happy now =)